# Can a decorator change a method's signature?

Tags: typescript

Consider a function:

```
function handleFoo(foo: number){
    // ...
}
```

I'd like to have a decorator which resolves foo, like:

```
@fetchFromApi('/foo')
function handleFoo(foo: number){
    // ...
}
```

where `@fetchFromApi` calls my API and then calls `handleFoo` with the result - at this point I would wish to call `handleFoo` without parameters, because `foo` is going to be `fetchedFromApi`. However, TypeScript's type checker still expects me to call `handleFoo` with a single argument.

Is it possible to change the decorated function's signature?

I've tried adjusting the return value of the decorator, like so:

```
return function (target: Object, name: string | symbol, descriptor: any): TypedPropertyDescriptor<() => void> { ... }
```

But then I just get:

```
Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.
    Type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<() => void>' is not assignable to type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<(foo: number) => void>'.
```

This is strange to me, it feels like there's no reason for it not to work - decorators are functions that process and return functions, correct? It seems to me that by specifying the return type of the decorator properly, one should be able to convince the TS type checker that the decorated function has a different signature.

Comment: No this is not possible via decorator, see [microsoft/TypeScript#4881](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) for the request/discussion for class decorators (although method decorators are mentioned in there too).  Some people feel very strongly that this should not be supported, while others feel equally strongly that it should.  The bottom line: nobody's going to touch this much until [the decorator proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators) reaches stage 3 at least.

Comment: Consider editing the code in the question to constitute a [mcve] as described in [ask] so I can modify it with possible workaround solutions.

Comment: Right, I did find that discussion, but since it's mainly about class decorators I wasn't sure if it really answers my question. Good to know, thanks - I'll leave this question open then in case this changes sometime in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. If you see the basic structure of decorator it actually takes the function(which you want to modify as one of the inputs) and then adds additional steps. So in that case you get only the early signature params.